# Netbeans run particular unit test with resource

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans

I use NetBeans 8.1. A project was created using an existing source. Build scripts was generated by NetBeans.
I have to write unit test for a library that will be dustributed as separated jar file. A method from this library try to get a resource file using code like

```
Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/text/text.txt");
```

The build script put required file to jar. When I try to run separate test file. Mentioned cannot find this resources. I cannot understand where this files schould be placed when particular unit test run. I try to put required files to folder build/test/

Comment: You can try to find out the place for the test with `System.out.println(new File("text/text.txt").getCanonicalPath())`. For better help a bit more information about the project would be helpful. What type is it? For example when you would use `File -> new project` what category and type is it?

Comment: I found the folowing solution: the absolute path in jar should be used /test/text.txt. For testing this files schall be placed in build/test/classes. @SibOptimal I use Java SE project

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` of a test class must be used, to have the correct class path to the resource (the test jar/test classes). Alternatively one can use the ClassLoader with "text/text.txt" (already absolute).